# how to customize y-axis step size in R

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to plot a scatterplot with y-axis is customized to step size of 0.2, within range of 0 - 2.6,  and x-axis can be auto-defined. I tried the below, but it doesnt work. May I know how should I set the param correctly?

---

```
# Read data
pt.n <- read.table("p0_n300m20r1c1_regression.txt", header=T)
# auto-scale
# plot(pt.n$maee~pt.n$idx, main="P2PSim Seq#1,300n,20%,1r,Corrective", ylab="MAEE", xlab="Seq #")

# customize
ylabel <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6)
y_range <- range(0, ylabel)
plot(pt.n$maee~pt.n$idx, main="P2PSim Seq#3,300n,20%,1r,Corrective", ylab="MAEE", xlab="Seq #", ylim=y_range, axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1, at=0:6, lab=c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300))
axis(2, las=1, at=0.2*0:y_range[1])
box()
```

Comment: Do you realize that `pt.n <- read.table("p0_n300m20r1c1_regression.txt", header=T)` throws an error for everyone but you?

Comment: this line works just fine on R 2.15.0. I have removed unnecessary parts of my code. So it might look odd, but it works just fine by plotting the graph correctly using the commented line #plot(..). Anyway.

Comment: Josh's point is that he does not have the file `p0_n300m20r1c1_regression.txt` - nor do I.  So we cannot run your code.

Comment: In this case the bit of the code that is important and not working doesn't require the data because the OP showed the actual code being used. I know we usually ask for a reproducible example but that is mainly needed in cases where it is not clear how the user's data is structured or what the actual error is. Asking for a reproducible example shouldn't be used in lieu of the rest of us reading the code to see what is wrong.

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- Fair enough and thanks for calling me on that. Also, twfx -- Apologies for my (misplaced) crankiness.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien No need to apologise - you were in the wrong place at the wrong time as I'd been meaning to comment about needing a balance when requesting fully reproducible answers. In general I agree do tend to agree with the point you and Henry raised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If something is not working check each bit of the thing that isn't doing what you want to make sure you are supplying the correct data and haven't made a booboo. If we run the bits of your code that are associated with the axis

```
ylabel <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6)
y_range <- range(0, ylabel)
0.2*0:y_range[1]
```

You would immediately see the problem:

```
R> 0.2*0:y_range[1]
[1] 0
```

where you are basically telling R to draw a tick at 0. Even if you chose the correct element of `y_range` (the maximum is in the *second* element) you still wouldn't get the right answer:

```
R> 0.2*0:y_range[2]
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.4
R> 0:y_range[2]
[1] 0 1 2
```

and that is because of the way the `:` operator works. A call of `x:y` is essentially a call to `seq(from = x, to = y, by = 1)` and because `2.6+1` is greater than `2.6` (the `to` argument) R creates the sequence `0, 1, 2`.

If you want to draw ticks and label at 0 - 2.6 incrementing by 0.2 then use:

```
ylabel <- seq(0, 2.6, by = 0.2)
axis(2, at = ylabel)
```

where `ylabel` now contains:

```
R> ylabel
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2.0 2.2 2.4 2.6
```

To illustrate:

```
dat <- data.frame(y = runif(20, min = 0, max = 3),
                  x = rnorm(20))

plot(y ~ x, data = dat, axes = FALSE)
ylabel <- seq(0, 2.6, by = 0.2)
axis(1)
axis(2, at = ylabel, las = 1)
box()
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: This is my very first R script. The technique of debugging you have elaborated values more than the answer given. I appreciate it very much. :).